# Tkinter button bind throws extra argument error

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments

I am trying to write `tkinter` code that calls a function either when a button is clicked or when enter is clicked when the button is in focus. I have the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

m = tk.Tk(className="My window")
def callback():
    print("Ice cream weather")

butt = tk.Button(m, text="My button", width=25, command=callback)
butt.grid()
butt.focus_set()
butt.bind('<Return>', callback)
m.mainloop()
```

But when I run it and press `Enter`, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chiller\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: callback() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I found a solution, which I posted below, but I am wondering if there is a simpler or neater fix.

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is to set the function up to take in a dummy parameter, and set a default value for when it isn't passed (i.e. for button click, which passes 0 arguments). This is just changing the line

```
def callback():
```

To

```
def callback(pointless=None):
```

This gives the extra parameter from pressing `Enter` a place to go, while not requiring it for a button push.